# Identify Feature by dragging polygon over datasets using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, identify

When using ArcGIS Desktop, I often use the Identify tool by clicking and dragging the tool over my data and identifying the features within it.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS or is setting the search radius within the map tools options the best that can be achieved for searching across multiple datasets?

Answer (score 2):

Search multiple layers with a mouse click is not a default setting in QGIS, I think it should be. Goto the menu Settings > Options > Map Tools, set the Identify mode to 'Top down'. Then the Identify feature tool will return info for all layers drilled into.

[image]

I am not aware of a tool that out of the box will act as a rectangle feature identify tool.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the top down option. I was more interested in the rectangle feature Identify tool. I feared there was no way to do it and you've confirmed this for me!