# Identify in QGIS by dragging polygon?

Tags: qgis, identify

In ArcMap it is possible to drag a polygon with the identify tool and thereby get information on multiple features without clicking on them with high precission.

So far I have not been able to find the same functionality in QGIS (checked all versons from 2.12 to 2.18.4).

Do you know a way to identify by dragging a polygon in QGIS?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate question of this: [QGIS Identify Feature tool by dragging a polygon over the datasets](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/qgis-identify-feature-tool-by-dragging-a-polygon-over-the-datasets). You could consider posting a [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) ticket as currently I don't think there is one describing this feature :)